# LightSwitch Add link inside a grid

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created a new "list and details" screen.
In the same window I show all "Order" entities and other depended entities called "OrderInfo" (one to many relation) 
The "OrderInfo" is displayed in a grid. 
I want to make one of the column inside the grid to be a link, so when user clicked on it, it will open another screen that shows the OrderInfo details.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for any string property of the entity that you're displaying in the grid. Simply tick the "Show As Link" box in the properties window).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make any field into a link in a Data Grid by checking the "Show as Link" property. But first you must make sure that the field is a 'Label' type, or else that option is not available.